# Are there post install tasks to perform for Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm supporting an installation of a Magento store that I didn't install or configure initially, and I'm not very familiar the software.

There are files such as install.php, magento-check.php, etc that don't seem to be part of the actual application... can/should these be removed from the installation directory, and are there any post-install tasks to perform for security etc that I should verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical Magento installation you use the server to restrict access to any files and directories outside of index.php

I would recommend setting up a local environment and upgrading to the latest version.

Magento also has an installation guide to follow to ensure you've set all permissions on files/directories correctly:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing